# How to update a field, after a view page is visited?

Tags: views, entities

Scenario:

I want to use a view to allow user to check a given code (string-like, eg "abc123") whether it is exists in the database, as well as whether the code has been checked before.

A content type called "code" is set up, has a field of "field_code_checked", either "0|Not yet checked" or "1|Checked",  and the title field represents the "code" string. The title field will be use as argument a.k.a the contextual filter of a view page to check the code.

So a view page 'check' is set up. 
http://mysite.com/check/[code-title]  => e.g  http://mysite.com/check/abc123

For example: 
If 'abc123' exists and field_code_checked value is '0' (not yet checked), then view will output the code node information.

My problem is: how can I manage to update 'field_code_checked' to 1, once a checking visit is done? So when abc123 node is created, it has a field_code_checked set to 0 by default, when a user visit http://mysite.com/check/abc123, I want field_code_checked of abc123 node set to be 1. 
Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up use the hook hook_views_post_render() to update field value.